# Short story where a main invents nanobots and reads a book in a radioactive room

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read (the beginning) of a short story about a man who invented nanobots.  He went into a radioactive room (nuclear reactor) where he trapped himself and started reading a book.

It may have been a short story written by Isaac Asimov, but I am not sure.

As far as I can remember, it was in a collection of short stories.  I also remember that during that time, I read Asimov's Science Fiction.  It was supposed to be continued on the next volume, but I did not find that volume.

I read that sometime between 1988 and 1992... but it was a bit older, when I read it.

Comment: Can you remember any extra details? Any character names or any more plot elements?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)! Sorry for posting two comments, this one is better.

Comment: @Edlothiad, I can not remember much more....  I wasn't able to finish reading it, as I could not find the next volume. 

I will read up on the guide, and see what I can remember.  Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not have firm proof of the scene you mentioned, but "[The Washer at the Ford](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?830162)" by Michael Flynn is about a group of scientists developing a nanotech protection from radiation and then debating the ethics of releasing it, namely about how the government might twist it, and the comment about the book sounds vaguely familiar. I don't know if it would help, but the phrase that stuck out in my memory involved a variation of "don't let the door hit you in the ass as you leave" by one of the scientists with the addition of a mention of the doorknob reaming them on their way.

I read it in *[The Nanotech Chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58419/23243)*, but the ISFDB entry lists a few dated anthologies. The other big catch is that it's at the upper range of your dates, as it was first serialized in 1989 in *Analog Science Fiction and Fact*, June 1989 & July 1989. user14111 was kind enough to provide a cover image, seen below, which shows the researcher reading a book in the reactor:

[image: Analog Science Fiction and Fact, June 1989 cover]

Comment: I firmly believe that this is the story I read.  I will try to get me a copy and read it again. 

Thank you so much, @FuzzyBoots

Comment: @azuer88: :) Well, as you can see through the link, I was the one asking after *The Nanotech Chronicles* a while back.